# Nginx keeps looking for index.html

Tags: php, nginx

http://localhost is showing a 404 by nginx 1.13.  When I look at the container logs I can see that nginx isn't passing the request off to php-fpm but is instead looking for an index.html.  **I can't figure out why it won't pass the request to php-fpm**.

**/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf**

I've verified this file is loaded.

```
server {
    listen   80;
    root /var/www/html/public;
    index index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    # look for local files on the container before sending the request to fpm
    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    # nothing local, let fpm handle it
    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass            localhost:9000;
        fastcgi_index           index.php;
        include                 fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param           REQUEST_METHOD  $request_method;
        fastcgi_param           SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param           QUERY_STRING    $query_string;
        fastcgi_param           CONTENT_TYPE    $content_type;
        fastcgi_param           CONTENT_LENGTH  $content_length;
        # Httpoxy exploit (https://httpoxy.org/) fix
        fastcgi_param           HTTP_PROXY "";

        # allow larger POSTS for handling stripe payment tokens
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
   }
}
```

Process list within the web container:

```
PID   USER     TIME   COMMAND
    1 root       0:00 s6-svscan -t0 /var/run/s6/services
   33 root       0:00 s6-supervise s6-fdholderd
  170 root       0:00 s6-supervise php-fpm
  171 root       0:00 s6-supervise nginx
  173 root       0:00 php-fpm: master process (/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.conf)
  174 root       0:00 {run} /bin/sh ./run
  177 root       0:00 nginx: master process nginx -g daemon off;
  187 nginx      0:00 nginx: worker process
  192 www-data   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
  193 www-data   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
  194 root       0:00 ps -ef
```

Container logs

```
web_1    | 2017/05/13 06:13:10 [error] 187#187: *1 "/etc/nginx/html/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.19.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "mysite.local"
web_1    | 172.19.0.1 - - [13/May/2017:06:13:10 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 571 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36"
```

**Update** Removed all references to index.htm per a few of the below comments

Comment: The error message suggests that this `server` block is not processing the request. By verified you mean `nginx -T`? Either remove the default server block or give this one a `server_name`.

Comment: it has `server_name ""` by default, ie. you never get this block with non-empty `Host` header, unless a `default_server` specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that despite my own vhosts configuration being in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`, `nginx -T` (which shows nginx's loaded configuration) didn't show the file having been read.

The `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;` directive was missing from my `nginx.conf`.

Answer (score 2):

By default, all of config files in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/` folder, including your file here `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`, are extended from `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.

In this config you did not specify `index` directive in `server {}` block. Then nginx will lookup the default in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.

Solution for this is override the default:

```
server {
    listen   80;
    root /var/www/html/public;
    charset utf-8;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
}
```

Then reset your nginx: `sudo service nginx restart`

Then `index.php` will have higher priority than the rest for nginx to lookup.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  After implementing that change and verifying it's in the filesystem by running `docker-compose exec web cat /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` I'm still seeing the problem.

Comment: Can you give me content of `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` file ? Better you login inside your container and check files that I mentioned. Because after change you also need to refresh your nginx also.

Comment: I've updated the above configuration.  I restarted by containers after making configuration changes to the virtual host.  The vhost file is provided via a mount, so that's sufficient for updating it.

Comment: If that, you can the original file before it's mounted to that container, then reload container to take effect. Because we are now facing with problem on nginx so any way you need to do so.

Answer (score 1):

`nginx` is using the default value for the `index` directive to process the URI `/` (as the directory does indeed exist).

You should add an explicit `index` statement to your `server` block.

```
server {
    ...
    index index.php;
    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    # nothing local, let fpm handle it
    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        ...
    }
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html#index) for more.